# must the Flash drive be FAT to be bootable?

Tags: boot, live-usb, unetbootin, startup-disk-creator

I used `Startup Disk Creator` to put an Ubuntu ISO file on a Flash drive FAT formatted. That booted.

I was not able to boot when I used `unetbootin` (Universal Net Boot Installer) to put the same Ubuntu ISO file on a Flash drive ext4 formatted.

The machine is a Samsung RF711.

Why was there a problem in the latter case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not necessary for the flash drive to be FAT to be bootable but as it stands now most devices are able to recognize natively FAT32 format be it your droid,tv  or something else. However you can boot from any format as long as your bootloader recognizes it.

If you are going to use `unetbootin` then I would recommend using a FAT32 format.

You can also copy a CD image directly to flash drive and make it bootable using `dd`

```
dd if=path/to/isofile.iso of=/dev/sdd
```

Replace `/dev/sdd` with your flash drive which you can find by,

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Comment: So what went wrong? I used the Ubuntu `Disks` utility to format for ext4. Why did that not boot? Why did `unetbootin` copy the ISO to the Flash drive without any complaint?

Comment: unetbootin just extracts files and puts it its own bootloader .....problem is that doesnt work so well with fs type other than FAT32 ...but you can boot from an ext4 formatted partition using bootloader like grub however installing grub to flash drive is a chore. Simplest solution is either use unetbootin on a FAT32 drive or use `dd ` command like i mentioned in my answer.

Comment: dd does an EXACT COPY of everything.  It is not trying to be "smart" like Clonezilla or the other utilities.  It simply copies blocks In From one source the Out File - a destination path.  /dev/sdd is common for a USB drive of any kind, but it also could be /dev/sdc or /dev/sd2 if there is a second partition so it is very important to do the `sudo fdisk -l` to see what your system thinks is out there.

Comment: @H.Freeze I'd suggest to add a warning as well for the `dd`-command. A simple typo could destroy the OS or other important data.`dd` is one of the commands we have to be double careful with. Otherwise correct answer, cheers...

Answer (score 0):

OK, sorry for reply only with the link. 
I edited my answer: 
It is due to the grub loader of the LiveUSB, bootx64.efi not load ext4 module. I by chance encounter the same problem, so I have solved it by making a new bootx64.efi. 
1. Recreate memdisk and config file

```
$mkdir memdisk
$nano memdisk/boot/grub/grub.cfg
           search --file --set=root /.disk/info
           set prefix=($root)/boot/grub
           source $prefix/x86_64-efi/grub.cfg
$tar cvf memdisk.tar memdisk/*
```

2. Recreate bootx64.efi with EXT4 support

```
$nano embeded.cfg
           insmod normal
           set root=(memdisk)
           set prefix=($root)/boot/grub
           source $prefix/grub.cfg 
$grub-mkimage  -o bootx64.efi -O x86_64-efi  fat  iso9660 part_gpt \  
      part_msdos normal boot linux configfile loopback \
      chain efifwsetup efi_gop efi_uga ls search search_label \
      search_fs_uuid search_fs_file gfxterm gfxterm_background \
      gfxterm_menu test all_video loadenv memdisk ext2 tar \
      -m memdisk.tar -c embeded.cfg
```

3. copy the bootx64.efi to your /efi/boot folder
Voila your EXT4 Live partition now boot as if a RAW iso image

Regards

my reference link [bootx64.efi for ext4 LiveUSB](https://github.com/sonvirgo/Ext4-LiveUSB)